# In case second highest value is missing then use the highest value of salary from employee table

Tags: oracle, rank

I have an employee table as below. As you can see that second highest salary is 200
Incase the second highest salary is missing then there will be only one row as shown at last . In this case the query should fetch only 100
I have written query as but it is not working. Please help! Thanks

select salary   "SecondHighestSalary" from(
(select id,salary,rank() over(order by salary desc) rnk
from employee2)
)a
where (rnk) in coalesce(2,1)

I have also tried the following but it is fetching 2 rows but i need only 1

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you just want `where rnk in (1,2)`.  `coalesce(2,1)` doesn't make sense-- 2 is obviously `not null` so that will always return 2.

Comment: I tried that too but it is fetching 2 rows if there are 2 rows. I have put that in my question

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd want something like

```
with ranked_emp as (
  select e.*, 
         rank() over (order by e.sal desc) rnk, 
         count(*) over () cnt
    from employee2 e
)
select salary "SecondHighestSalary"
  from ranked_emp
 where (rnk = 2 and cnt > 1)
    or (rnk = 1 and cnt = 1)
```

Note that I'm still using `rank` since you're using that in your approach and you don't specify how you want to handle ties.  If there are two employees with the same top salary, `rank` will assign both a `rnk` of 1 and no employee would have a `rnk` of 2 so the query wouldn't return any data.  `dense_rank` would ensure that there was at least one employee with a `rnk` of 2 if there were employees with at least 2 different salaries.  If there are two employees with the same top salary, `row_number` would arbitrarily assign one the `rnk` of 2.  The query I posted isn't trying to handle those duplicate situations because you haven't outlined exactly how you'd want it to behave in each instance.

Comment: Thanks Justin i am using oracle 11g i am getting invalid number of arguments in count() over () cnt in the select never used this one previously. Any thoughts Thanks

Comment: @Lara - Sorry, corrected the typo.  Should have been `count(*)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Oracle 12.2 or higher, you can try:

```
select distinct id,
 nvl
(
 nth_value(salary, 2) from first 
 over(partition by id 
      order by salary desc 
      range between unbounded preceding and unbounded 
      following), 
 salary
) second_max_salary
 from employee2
```